jitsi / jitsimeet not working with react native 0.73
I am upgrading my app From react-native 0.66 to react-native 0.72 and while installing jitsi/react-native-sdk the following error pops up
node_modules/react-native-webview/lib/RNCWebViewNativeComponent.js: /Users/lmdi/Documents/FlameApps-ReactV2/node_modules/react-native-webview/lib/RNCWebViewNativeComponent.js: Could not find component config for native component
my current packages and version
"dependencies": {
    "@amplitude/react-native": "2.7.0",
    "@braintree/sanitize-url": "7.0.0",
    "@dashdoc/react-native-system-sounds": "^1.1.0",
    "@giphy/react-native-sdk": "2.3.0",
    "@jitsi/react-native-sdk": "^2.2.1",
    "@mapbox/polyline": "^1.2.1",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.19.4",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^19.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^19.1.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "10.1.0",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.72.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "@terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas": "^0.8.0",
    "@wili/react-native-perspective-image-cropper": "file:Custom_components/react-native-perspective-image-cropper",
    "aes-js": "^3.1.2",
    "dateformat": "^5.0.3",
    "entities": "^4.5.0",
    "geolib": "^3.3.4",
    "jail-monkey": "^2.8.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "next-frame": "^0.2.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-audio-record": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-axios": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-background-timer": "2.4.1",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-beautiful-video-recorder": "file:Custom_components/react-native-beautiful-video-recorder",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.8",
    "react-native-calendar-events": "2.2.0",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1304.1",
    "react-native-compressor": "^1.8.24",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-create-thumbnail": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-custom-web-view": "file:Custom_components/react-native-custom-web-view",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-default-preference": "1.4.4",
    "react-native-device-info": "10.9.0",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.1.1",
    "react-native-draggable": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.4",
    "react-native-element-textinput": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-exit-app": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-floating-action": "^1.22.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-fused-location": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "1.9.0",
    "react-native-image-base64": "^0.1.4",
    "react-native-image-marker": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.2",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-image-rotate": "file:Custom_components/react-native-image-rotate",
    "react-native-image-to-pdf": "file:Custom_components/react-native-image-to-pdf",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-immersive-mode": "2.0.1",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "4.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-localize": "^3.0.6",
    "react-native-location": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-map-link": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.11.3",
    "react-native-orientation-locker": "1.6.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-paper": "5.10.3",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.4",
    "react-native-performance": "5.0.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^4.1.5",
    "react-native-photo-editor": "^1.0.13",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.3",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.11.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.24.0",
    "react-native-shake": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-shimmer-placeholder": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.12",
    "react-native-simple-custom-radio-button": "file:Custom_components/react-native-simple-custom-radio-button",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-sms": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-sound": "0.11.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.3.0",
    "react-native-ssl-pinning": "^1.5.7",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.13.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-thumbnail": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-tts": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-video": "6.0.0-alpha.11",
    "react-native-video-player": "^0.14.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "react-native-watch-connectivity": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-web-service-handler": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-webrtc": "118.0.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.5.1",
    "react-native-webview-invoke": "^0.6.2",
    "react-xml-parser": "^1.1.8",
    "realm": "^12.6.2",
    "rn-document-scanner-letmedoit": "^0.0.3",
    "rn-vertical-slider": "^4.0.0",
    "scrollable-tab-lmdi": "^1.0.0",
    "text-encoding": "0.7.0",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0"
  },

metro config:
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');
/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const path = require('path');
const {
    resolver: {sourceExts, assetExts},
} = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const config = {
    transformer: {
        babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
    },
    resolver: {
        assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
        sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
        resolverMainFields: ['sbmodern', 'react-native', 'browser', 'main'],
    },
    watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../')],
};
module.exports = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, config);

if anymore details required please ask
I am upgrading my app From react-native 0.66 to react-native 0.72 and while installing jitsi/react-native-sdk
